# Using "Counter" in Python 3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to use the `Counter` method in Python 3.2 but I'm not sure if I'm  using it properly. Any idea why I'm getting the error?

```
>>> import collections
>>> Counter()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    Counter()
NameError: name 'Counter' is not defined
```

I can access the `Counter` if I go `collections.Counter()`, but not the examples in the documentation.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You want `from collections import Counter`. Using `import collections` only makes the stuff in collections available as collections.*something*. More on modules and the workings of `import` in the first few sections of [this tutorial chapter](http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/modules.html).

Answer (score 7):

Try this its working fine using Counter

```
import collections
print collections.Counter(['a','b','c','a','b','b'])
```

Output:

```
Counter({'b': 3, 'a': 2, 'c': 1})
```

Comment: it doesn't looks like python 3.2 it looks like 2.7 or 2.x

Comment: The heading is "Using Counter in Python 3.2". And what does this add to the accepted answer? Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)